# Only publish on Redis if someone is actually subscribing

Tags: redis

Is it possible with `Redis` to only `PUBLISH` if someone is actually `SUBSCRIBE` to a channel?

Answer (score 1):

Nope - PubSub in general, and also in Redis, is a methodology in which publishers and subscribers are oblivious of each other and the only "contract" between them is the channel they use.